# JQuery: when mousedown on child object, trigger only parent object not child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to trigger parent div not child when mousedown/mousemove on child element. I am designing a object say [square] with the restricted area, It is working fine when I am moving slow mouse within area, but when I move fast It moves out of the restricted area, How can I make it in the restricted area? I don't want to use any plugin.

Comment: Can you show us your code

Comment: sorry you need to explain what you are looking for more clearly

Comment: Need more info, but I'm guessing this is an event.target vs. event.currentTarget situation.

Comment: `I just want to trigger parent div` Add event listener in capturing phase, and stop propagation in event handler

Comment: I have got my answer, please someone upvote it, If it needs more clarification, please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Stop immediate propagation on child event, trigger parent event manually

```
$(".restricted.child").on('mousedown', function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).closest(".parent").trigger('mousedown');
});
```

**Edit:**

Based on your updated description, I think this is the closest you can get.

The child event is triggered, there is no getting around that, but you can use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` to keep other handlers from being executed and prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

You can then trigger the same event on the parent. There are a number of ways to target the parent, but I used the `.closest()` method to target just this child's closest parent that has the `.parent` class.

```js
$(".restricted.child").on('mousedown', function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).closest(".parent").trigger('mousedown');
});

$(".child").on('mousedown', function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('child-alt');
});

$(".parent").on('mousedown', function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('parent-alt');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    background-color: ForestGreen;
}

.child {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    background: DodgerBlue;
}

.parent-alt {
    border-radius: 200px;
    background-color: Plum;
}

.child-alt {
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: Chocolate;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1em;
}

p {
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Restricted<br />propagation</h2>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="restricted child"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Restricted child's event is halted, but the parent event is triggered manually.</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Natural<br />propagation</h2>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Unrestricted child's event will fire and the parent event is fired naturally.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It will prevent trigger parent element not child.

Comment: Right. I must have misunderstood, I thought you wanted to be able to prevent the parent from being triggered by a child event. But I see your update says the opposite.

Comment: Your question and description are still is a bit confusing. Can you provide a code sample of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Simply, I want, If I mousedown on child, parent event should trigger ignoring child event.

Comment: @user1598937 I have updated my answer and the fiddle with an example that I believe addresses your scenario.

Comment: hello, IHBAW but I was wondering if you could help me with this same problem I'm having PLUS the fact that I need to use `e` inside the parent's handler and when I trigger the event from the child, `e.pageX` comes out `undefined` in the parent's handler, something like `$(".parent").on('mousedown', function (e) {$(this).toggleClass('parent-alt'); console.log(e.pageX);});` thanx

Comment: @Scaramouche You can pass the original event along with the newly triggered event as a second parameter to jQuery's [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). For example: `$(this).closest(".parent").trigger('mousedown', e);` Then just allow a second argument in the handler function. For example: `$(".parent").on('mousedown', function (e, oe) { console.log('originalEvent', oe); });`